# No instantiation of Case tokens in mails sent by CiviRules

Tags: civicase, tokens, civirules

I am trying to send emails (with case tokens) with CiviRules but I do not get the tokens instantiations.

The environment: I use CiviRules, Compucorp CiviCase. I have activated email Api extension, Civicase tokens.  And I have the last available versions. I am on Wordpress 5.7.1. And CiviCRM 5.36.

The rule: Trigger of the rule is "case activity added", mails are sent to target of this activity and to a role (case coordinator) of the case. In the mails templates I have case tokens (subject and custom fields).

The result: Rule is triggered, mails are actually sent to the activity target and the role. The role is therefore recognized (he gets the mail, without the tokens instantiation). Case Tokens are not resolved.
When I send the mail (same template) manually inside the case, then the result is ok.
Very puzzling!

Comment: I'm dealing with same issue here! If you have any solution please share.

Comment: I have not solved the issue and I try to find a workaround with some code (api template mail). Still a struggle.

Comment: I ended up coding all the emails I wanted to automate.